# MFC - Insert item in CTreeCtrl behaving different in Windows 10

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am seeing a peculiar behavior when inserting an item in the tree control (CTreeCtrl) in my MFC application in Windows 10 operating system whereas if the same code is run on Windows XP it works properly.

The issue is if I insert an item "abcd++" with InsertItem or SetItem API, it gets inserted as "**++abcd**" *(special symbol changes position)* in Windows 10 and "abcd++" in the Win XP. Same, if I insert an item ":=abcd-+", it gets inserted as "**+-abcd=:**" *(special symbol changes position)* in Windows 10 and ":=abcd-+" in the Win XP.

I am not sure why this peculiar behavior in Windows 10? Has anyone experienced the same or similar behavior? Please help.

Thanks,

Nayan Soni

Comment: Do you run Windows configured with a right-to-left locale (e.g. Arabic), by any chance?